# My pointer in an array doesn't work as it supposed to

Tags: c

I wanted to create a function, that would accept an 1:array_of_int, and 2:size_of_array, then return sum of the 3 biggest int. Code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max_3(int arr[], int asize)
{ 
   int max_arr[3];
   int max =0; 
   int sum = 0;
   int* pi; 

   for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
   {   
      for(int i =0; i<asize;i++)
      {   
         if(arr[i] > max)
         {
           max = arr[i];
           pi = (arr + i); // to know the address of the max int of 'i' cycle
         }
      }   
      max_arr[j] = max;
      *pi = 0; // make the max int = 0 so that the next 'i' cycle doesnt have the previous max in it 
               //(so it can look for another max value - the second one)
   }   

   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
      sum += max_arr[i];

   return sum;
}


int main (int argc, char** argv) {
   int arr[6] = {1,5,9,12,16,14};
   printf("%i\n",max_3(arr, 6));
   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The pointer `pi` doesn't make the value of the current `max` value 0, and the next cycle in `for (int i..)` make the biggest one again as from the previous. So instead of returning max val1 + val2 + val3, it returned 3 * val1 (the biggest one) -- in my particular example - it printed out `48` instead of `42` (12 + 16 + 14) - as it should. But how when I make the value of address (which my pointer point to) as `0`? I do not understand that properly.

Comment: Have you tried to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? What if you use a variable to store the *index* of the max element (instead of a pointer) will that index be correct? Does the code work using the index instead?

Comment: And a small hint: After the inner loop, what is the value of `max`? Where do you *reset* it? That should be *very* easy to find out with a little debugging.

Comment: That the function modifies the input array would be very surprising to most users.

Comment: @molbdnilo how does it modifies? If I make some sorting - then would be the array modified, but in my example, i make 'auxiliary' array `max_arr` and store the max values in there, so that i dont mofidy the input array `arr` - so it does the opposite of what you said.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the value of max int is everytime something different - in both loops - as it is shown - `if(arr[i]>max) max = arr[i]` - and again if something is bigger then the max in that array afterward - then it becomes max. every single cycle. Thats the reason, why it is stored in function space - not inside loops

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int main (int argc, char** argv)`  The two parameters are not used.  This will cause the compiler to output two warning messages.  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: @PatrikPatanPastyyr `pi` points into `arr`– `pi = (arr + i)` – and then you write into it with `*pi = 0;`. If you print your array afterwards in `main` you will see that it has become `{1,5,9,12,0,14}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement:

```
if (arr[i] > max)
```

isn't going to be entered after the first time you find `max` (*i.e.* when `j > 0`).

You need to zero it after:

```
max_arr[j] = max;
max = 0;
```

Comment: unfortunally still getting `48` instead of `42`. I think, regardless if i make the value in max = 0, it is still in the array `arr` (the max value - e.g. `16` - in my specific exapmle), so i have to delete (aka make it zero) the `max` in that array - therefor trying to point to that addaress.

Comment: @PatrikPatanPastyyr I can not reproduce the problem. Your code outputs 42.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow neither I do, but as i just add one row  `max = 0;` after row `max_arr[j] = max;` - it printed 48.

Comment: @PatrikPatanPastyyr As I already wrote I can reproduce this result.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. performs the desired functionality
2. is very straight forward in its' algorithm
3. incorporates a bubble sort for selecting the top three entries in the array
4. eliminates the 'magic' number 6
5. modifies the second parameter to type `size_t` as that is the type returned by `sizeof()`
6. the expression: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` lets compiler calculate number of entries in array
7. the statement: `int arr[] = {1,5,9,12,16,14};` lets compiler allocate room for array
8. avoids modifying the original array, when sorting

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  // memcpy()


void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 


// A function to implement bubble sort 
void bubbleSort(int arr[], size_t n) 
{ 
    size_t i;
    size_t j; 
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)  
    {     
       // Last i elements are already in place    
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
       {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
            {
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
            }
        }
    }
} 


int max_3(int arr[], size_t asize)
{ 
    int localArray[ asize ];
    memcpy( localArray, arr, asize*sizeof( int ) );
    // sort array
    bubbleSort( localArray, asize );

    // calculate sum of max 3 entries
    int sum = localArray[asize-1] + localArray[asize-2] + localArray[asize-3];
    return sum;
}   


int main ( void ) 
{
   int arr[] = {1,5,9,12,16,14};
   printf( "%i\n", max_3( arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])) );
   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

a run of the proposed code results in:

```
42
```

Comment: but the difference is that my function volume is something about 30 rows, but youts is maybe 110 (havent counted it). And - moreover - the bublesort is one of the most depricated sorts, since is difficulty is x^2. Anyway if i wanted to make a sort, i would use qsort() implemented function, but that wasnt the purpose.

Comment: what do you mean by: `function volume`?

Comment: The `bubble sort` is (about) the best when the number of entries to sort is less than 10.

Comment: A bubble sort does not 'scale' well, however, the OP did not mention anything about a much larger array.  AND if it were a much larger array, then the function: `qsort()` would be an appropriate function

Comment: volume - number of rows

Comment: 'number of rows'?  Perhaps you meant number of C statements.  In general, less statements doesn't mean more efficient

Answer (score 0):

After the very first iteration of the outer loop (the loop `for(int j=0; j<3; j++)`) the value of `max` and `pi` will never change.

In that first iteration of the outer loop, you will find that the fifth element in the array will be largest, `max` will be equal to `16` and `pi` will point to that element. You set `max_arr[0]` to `16` and set `*pi` to zero. Then the outer loop starts over with `max` still being equal to `16`. And now there will be no value in the array that will be equal or larger than that. So you set `max_arr[1]` to `16` as well, and set `*pi` (where `pi` is still pointing to the fifth element) to zero *again*. And the same thing the next iteration.

The natural solution would be to define `max` and `pi` *inside* the outer loop:

```
for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    // The variables will be redefined and reinitialized each iteration of the loop
    int max = 0;
    int *pi;

    for(int i =0; i<asize;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
            pi = (arr + i); // to know the address of the max int of 'i' cycle
        }
    }
    max_arr[j] = max;
    *pi = 0; // make the max int = 0 so that the next 'i' cycle doesnt have the previous max in it
             //(so it can look for another max value - the second one)
}
```

There are a few other problems with the code, like for example the possibility that `pi` will never be initialized. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure when that will happen and how to solve it.